# Smooth div scroll: Last picture falls to the bottom line

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, smooth-scrolling

My scroll works perfectly with the normal configuration.

```
#makeMeScrollable{
  width:100%;
  height: 500px;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:110px;
}

#makeMeScrollable div.scrollableArea img{
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  padding: 0; 
}
```

But when the window height is less than 768px, I made the following change in the CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-height : 768px) {
    #makeMeScrollable{
      height: 500px;
    }

    #makeMeScrollable div.scrollableArea img{
        height: 400px
    }
}
```

Works fine on Chrome, but on Firefox and IE the last image drop to the bottom line.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you change the CSS for the images using padding instead of margin? Like this:

```
#makeMeScrollable div.scrollableArea img{
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 5px 0 0; 
}
```

This has worked for me sometimes in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it somehow like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({                 
            manualContinuousScrolling: false,
            autoScrollingMode: "onStart",
            autoScrollingDirection: "backAndForth",
            autoScrollingStep: 1
        });
    });
```

This was the first script to initialize it. I was hoping the images to go back and forth.

I made it like this and now the problem is solved with me:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({                 
            manualContinuousScrolling: true,
            autoScrollingMode: "onStart",
            autoScrollingStep: 1
        });
    });
```